# Using Thrust to construct multiple histograms from a single array

Tags: cuda, thrust

Let us say that I have a single array which stores time stamps for multiple events. For example, T1_e1, T2_e1,....,T1_e2, T2_e2, T3_e2,.....T1_eN, T2,eN,..

I know that Thrust offers a function which computes adjacent differences, but here I need to do it for multiple events. Basically, constructing multiple histograms from a single input array.

So the output would have N different histograms (one for each event) like this:
histogram bins for e1, histogram bins for e2, histogram bins for e3,....histogram bins for eN.

```
Input1 (timestamps): 100, 101, 104, 105, 101,104, 106, 111, 90, 91, 93,  94,95
Input2 (events):    4123,4123,4123,4123,2129,2129,2129,2129,300,300,300,300,300

output: 4123:(1,2),(2,0),(3,1),(4,0),(5,0)
        2129:(1,0),(2,1),(3,1),(4,0),(5,1)
        300: (1,2),(2,1),(3,0),(4,),(5,0)
```

The number of bins will be fixed, i.e. 5 bins per histogram.
Regarding the tuples: (x,y) -> x is the difference between two consecutive time stamps belonging to the same event. y is the count.

If we consider event 4123, the first tuple is (1,2), because the difference between 101 and 100 is 1, and 105 and 104 is 1. So there are two time stamp differences which belong to this bin, hence (1,2).

Can someone please suggest the most efficient way to do this. So far, it seems that I will have to write my own code. But if there are existing solutions, I would like to try them first.

Comment: I suggest you add some clarity around the data you would like to produce.  Do you want the difference from every timestamp to every other timestamp?  What do you mean multiple histograms?

Comment: I'm not sure this need be any different than an ordinary single histogram.  Numerically, if you combine your event and timestamp pairs into a single quantity, the high order portion being the event, and the low order portion being the timestamp, your histogram will naturally separate itself by events.  The thrust [histogram example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/histogram.cu) might be a good starting point.  If you give a sample actual data set and sample actual expected results, I imagine someone might be willing to give you some sample code.

Comment: [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_histogram.html) also has histogramming functions.

Comment: Updated the post with sample input, and expected output.

Comment: I don't really understand your bins.  I understand that there are 5 bins, but I don't understand how you decide which timestamps belong in which bins.

Comment: Is the number of bins fixed? Or does it vary for the different event histograms? Could you also please explain in more detail what the meaning of those tuples `(1,2)...` is and how they are constructed from the given input data?

Comment: Please see the example I just added

Comment: Is the number of timestamps per event variable?

Comment: Yes, the number of time stamps can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible approach that computes the sparse histogram (i.e. non-zero bins only).  It should not be difficult to convert a sparse histogram to a dense histogram (zero and non-zero bins included) using thrust scattering.

1. compute the timestamp differences using `thrust::adjacent_difference` and a special functor (`my_adj_diff`) that computes adjacent differences only for like events.
2. use `thrust::remove_if` to remove the zero values (one per event) at the start of each event sequence (created by the functor in step 1).
3. combine events and timestamp differences into a single integer for histogramming using `thrust::transform`.  This just multiplies the event by 100 in my example, and adds the timestamp difference (assumed to be a set of bins of less than 100 max bin).
4. use the sparse histogram method from the thrust [histogram example code](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/histogram.cu).

Here's a fully worked example.  The data does not quite match your expected output (non-zero values only) because you have an error in your expected output.

```
$ cat t678.cu
#include <thrust/adjacent_difference.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>


#include <iostream>

#define ZIP(X,Y) thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(X,Y))
#define SCALE 100

struct my_adj_diff
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  T operator()(T &d2, T &d1) const
    {
      if (thrust::get<1>(d1) == thrust::get<1>(d2)) {
        thrust::get<0>(d2) -= thrust::get<0>(d1);}
      else {
        thrust::get<0>(d2) = 0;}
      return d2;
    }
};

struct my_is_zero
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const T &d1) const
    {
      return (thrust::get<0>(d1) == 0);
    }
};

struct my_combine
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  T operator()(const T &d1, const T &d2) const
    {
      return (d1*SCALE)+d2;
    }
};

// sparse histogram using reduce_by_key
// modified from: https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/histogram.cu
template <typename Vector1,
          typename Vector2,
          typename Vector3>
void sparse_histogram(const Vector1& input,
                            Vector2& histogram_values,
                            Vector3& histogram_counts)
{
  typedef typename Vector1::value_type ValueType; // input value type
  typedef typename Vector3::value_type IndexType; // histogram index type
  thrust::device_vector<ValueType> data(input);

  // sort data to bring equal elements together
  thrust::sort(data.begin(), data.end());

  // number of histogram bins is equal to number of unique values (assumes data.size() > 0)
  IndexType num_bins = thrust::inner_product(data.begin(), data.end() - 1,
                                             data.begin() + 1,
                                             IndexType(1),
                                             thrust::plus<IndexType>(),
                                             thrust::not_equal_to<ValueType>());

  // resize histogram storage
  histogram_values.resize(num_bins);
  histogram_counts.resize(num_bins);

  // compact find the end of each bin of values
  thrust::reduce_by_key(data.begin(), data.end(),
                        thrust::constant_iterator<IndexType>(1),
                        histogram_values.begin(),
                        histogram_counts.begin());

}


int main(){

  int tstamps[] = { 100, 101, 104, 105, 101,104, 106, 111, 90, 91, 93,  94,95 };
  int mevents[] = {4123,4123,4123,4123,2129,2129,2129,2129,300,300,300,300,300};
  int dsize = sizeof(tstamps)/sizeof(int);

  thrust::host_vector<int>   h_stamps(tstamps, tstamps+dsize);
  thrust::host_vector<int>   h_events(mevents, mevents+dsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_stamps = h_stamps;
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_events = h_events;
  thrust::device_vector<int> diffs(dsize);
  // compute timestamp differences by event
  thrust::adjacent_difference(ZIP(d_stamps.begin(), d_events.begin()), ZIP(d_stamps.end(), d_events.end()), ZIP(d_stamps.begin(), d_events.begin()), my_adj_diff());
  d_stamps[0] = 0;  // fix up first event for adjacent_difference
  int sz1 = thrust::remove_if(ZIP(d_stamps.begin(), d_events.begin()), ZIP(d_stamps.end(), d_events.end()), my_is_zero()) - ZIP(d_stamps.begin(), d_events.begin());
  d_stamps.resize(sz1);
  d_events.resize(sz1);
  // pack events and timestamps into a single vector - assumes max bin (time difference) is less than SCALE
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_data(sz1);
  thrust::transform(d_events.begin(), d_events.end(), d_stamps.begin(), d_data.begin(), my_combine());
  // compute histogram
  thrust::device_vector<int> histogram_values;
  thrust::device_vector<int> histogram_counts;
  sparse_histogram(d_data, histogram_values, histogram_counts);
  thrust::copy(histogram_values.begin(), histogram_values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(histogram_counts.begin(), histogram_counts.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc t678.cu -o t678
$ ./t678
30001,30002,212902,212903,212905,412301,412303,
3,1,1,1,1,2,1,
$
```

Note that you will need to use CUDA 7.0 (not CUDA 7.0 RC or any earlier version of CUDA) or else download the latest thrust master branch [from github](https://github.com/thrust/thrust), because older versions of thrust have an [issue](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/574) when attempting to use zip iterators with `thrust::adjacent_difference`.